# Integrate Exponential function with Integration Variable e (de)

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I have the following problem: How do i integrate this: $ \int^1_0 e^{x^2+3 } de $ ? 
Whats putting me off is the de, i don't know how to integrate over the e-function...

According to Wolfram Alpha, it's the function itself: $ e^{x^2+3 } $

But how do i get there? I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: $$ \int^1_0 e^{x^2+3 } de = \frac{e^{x^2+4}}{x^2+4}\Big|_0^1 = \frac{1}{x^2+4}.$$

Comment: We are verging on the absurd here... It might be the time to try to **understand** what it is we are talking about.

Comment: Your solution differs from the one Wolfram Alpha gives me... I am still confused.. You are simply integrating it, but i don't know if thats right

Comment: @user2170318 WolframAlpha doesn't like integrating over $e$. Maybe you should use different variables - try integrating $x^{y^2+3} \mathrm{d}x$, for example

Comment: This was actually a task in an exam, and my prof confirmed afterwards, that it was actually the Euler's number and not just a variable.. Thats why i'm so confused!

Comment: Does this change the outcome somehow??

Comment: But you can't integrate over a constant...  I think it's time to get a clear definition from the professor of what such an operation would mean...  In particular $e\Big|_0^1=e-e=0$ because $e$ takes on only the value $\sum_{i=0}^\infty{1\over i!}$...

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: it does not really matter what the variable you are integrating with respect to is denoted by. All following integrals represent the same thing - the same number: $$\int_0^1x^ndx=\int_0^1y^ndy=\int_0^1a^nda=\int_0^1e^nde=\int_0^1\otimes^nd\otimes$$

Now set $n=x^2+3$, this is just a constant with respect to $e$. Also to distract your mind from the conventional treatment of $e$ call it $t$ temporarely: $e=t$. Thus you arrive to $$\int_0^1t^ndt=\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{x^3+4}$$

This is an example of an irritating  notation or perhaps an exercise to teach students that it is irrelevant how we denote variables.

Comment: Thanks, i got that now, i will ask my prof tomorrow if this is correct, if not i'm gonna let you know, but i don't know what it could be then.. ^^

Comment: Ok, he said it was just a variable, he misunderstood my earlier question and said it was the euler number... :/